# How to force Jackson XmlMapper to write all element names in upper case?

Tags: java, jackson

I am writing xml with this code:

```
XmlMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
    objectMapper.configure( ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true );
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    String xml = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(report);
```

Is there anyway to configure the mapper to write the element names in upper case, or do I need to annotate each field in `report` with an uppercased name?

Comment: Hi @ab11, did you have any solution for the problem? I have the same requirement. Thanks!